# Deploy SPFx client web part to SP 2016 On Premises

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, deployment, spfx-webparts, cdn

I try to deploy a SharePoint Framework Client Webpart to SP 2016 On-Premises which has also custom js-file which should be hosted on the target SP2016 box in a assets library.
What I understand from the documentation is: assign the path of the assets library in write-manifests.json like so:

```
"cdnBasePath": "https://sharepoint2016.test.de/SiteAssets/SPFx%20Client%20WebParts/SEM%20Activities"
```

I ran

```
gulp bundle --ship
```

to find related files in temp/deploy-folder.
I uploaded these files to the assets library which I had configured in cdnBasePath.
Then i ran

```
gulp package-solution --ship
```

to create the package.

I added the package to the AppCatalog and then added the app to my site Collection. Which succeeds.
When I then click on the app to see my web part in Action I get an error (the typicall 'Something went wrong').
From the Correlation-Id I found this entry:

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
at     Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppRedirectPage.ValidateAndProcessRequest()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppRedirectPage.HandleRequest()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppRedirectPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Is there may be some other configuration missing?

When I use

```
gulp serve
```

to run the webpart on the Workbench everything works fine.
I found no complete guide and no specification on how to deploy such artifacts to On-Premises.

Any hint is appreciated.
With Kind regards, Ronny

Comment: same problem here... Did you found an solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a webpart, you don't need to enter your App (like you would a SPHA), you simply add the webpart as you normally would on a page through the Add Webpart ribbon item.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for the quick Response. I just realized that. When I add the App to a site Collection, I can add the WebPart from the Ribbon of a page. Is it by design that this sort of Webparts are not shown in the webpart Gallery?

Comment: I can't answer that one for sure, but since SPFx webparts aren't traditional webparts, that is likely why they don't show up in the webpart gallery.